# How to limit resultSet size when I retrieve tables from database

Tags: jdbc

Here, the source code that retrieve the tables of a database:

```
    DatabaseMetaData dmd = connection.getMetaData();
    ResultSet resultSet = dmd.getTables(connection.getCatalog(), null, null, TABLE_TYPES);
    while(resultSet.next()){
        treeMap.put(resultSet.getString(TABLE_NAME), new ArrayList<>());
        ResultSet fields = dmd.getColumns(null, null, resultSet.getString(TABLE_NAME), null);
        while(fields.next()){
            treeMap.get(resultSet.getString(TABLE_NAME)).add(fields.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
        }
    }
    connection.close();
    treeMap.forEach((s, strings) -> System.out.println(s+" -> "+String.join(",",strings)));
    return treeMap;
```

Comment: What, exactly, is the question? You just dumped some code.

Comment: do you mean how to limit rows of tables to display in resultset?

Comment: yes, the question is how to limit rows of tables to display in resultset?